# Entity Framework map entity to linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am a new in Entity framework (I am using 6.0, but if I need I can update), I am looking for a way to bind  entity to linq query. For example I have:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public WorkPlace Place {get;set;}
    public bool IsAlive{get;set;}
}

public class WorkPlace
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
    public Collection<User> Users;
}
```

Both of them are mapped to tables in a database and I have the `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(tableName: "users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkPlace>().ToTable(tableName: "workplaces");
}
```

But I need to use another object (with navigation and lazy loading):

```
public class CustomUser
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public CustomWorkPlace Place {get;set;}
}

public class CustomWorkPlace
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Collection<CustomUser> Users;
}

someBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>().ToLinq(cntx => cntx.Set<User>().Where(user => user.IsAlive)).MapProperties(); 
// the way of mapping properties is not important
someBuilder.Entity<CustomWorkPlace>().ToLinq(cntx => cntx.Set<WorkPlace>().Where(place => plase.IsActive)).MapProperties()
```

And the most interesting thing of that is going through the navigation, when I get company of an user, I must not get a company which is not active, and the same for a company - I must not get any `CustomUser` which is mapped to not alive User.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I implement this logic (getting my custom objects from context) by entity framework or a nuget extention.

Comment: Just use your normal entity to load the data and create the custom one from there, no?

Comment: By this way I cannot use navigations

Comment: Why could you not?

Comment: I can get all Users from the context and convert them to CustomUsers, but I do not know how can I map navigations (I have to keep lazy loading) and I have to map not all entities (only that entities for a user, which IsActive) - I do not know how to implement it, the method "ToLinq" in my post is just a pseudo code.

Comment: Ok, i get it.  You can look up my answer to see if it answer your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129069/discussion-between-vvildvvolf-and-kinetic).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a proper getter, such as:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public WorkPlace Place get{ return this.WorkPlace.Where(x => x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();}
    public bool IsAlive{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I have to hide unuseful properties (like IsAlive) from the levelUp developers (they should not know about this field), and the FirstOrDefault method (as I know) will materialize this query but developers need for building some selects as usual (but I do not have to support inserting and updating).

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your navigation properties like this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(tableName: "users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkPlace>().ToTable(tableName: "workplaces");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasRequired(user => user.Place)
        .WithMany(place => place.Users);
}
```

Then you can do your query using your navigation properties.

```
public List<CustomUser> GetActiveCustomuser()
{
    return context.Users
       .Where(u => u.Active)
       .Select(new CustomUser() 
           { 
               Name = u.Name, 
               Place = new CustomPlace() { Name = u.Place.Name }
           })
       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is not clear in my Question, but I need for queryable collection (to make some selects), and the navigations have to be lazy